# spring boot use Environment load yml to map

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, yaml

I have the yml like :

```
application:
  address:
   '0xb7716e1f5690a841d698dd64ae13727bf719b2cd': '4'
   '0x0f020200ad0729f19be98ddb26685d80359428b7': '5'
```

I `Autowired` the Environment variable as below -

```
@Autowired
Environment environment;
```

And now `getProperty` of environment returns `null`

```
Map<String,String> maps = environment.getProperty("application.address",HashMap.class); //got null
```

How to get the address as map type?

Comment: Try to declare this variable `@Value("${application.address}") Map<String,String> maps;`. Is your yml named application.yml (default name used by spring boot to find your configuration) ?

Comment: `Could not resolve placeholder 'application.address' in value "${application.address}"` same no useful.

Comment: You could try with `@ConfigurationProperties` (https://www.mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-configurationproperties-example/)

Comment: working on it  `@ConfigurationProperties("application")` thank  for you

Answer (score 0):

`@ConfigurationProperties("application")`

and set a variable to revice 
`private Map<String,String> address;`

and add get and set method

`public Map<String, String> getAddress() {
   return address;
}`

`public void setAddress(Map<String, String> address) {
  this.address = address;
}`

you got it